# Sharepoint 2013 Blog - Change font size on post title

Tags: css, blog

Good Morning;

I am currently working on a Sharepoint BLOG. I have been able to increase the size of text within the post using CSS. What is the label for the Title of the post, so that I can change that text size as well?

Also, is there a code to remove the hyperlink attached to the title of the post?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you the exact class or ID of this element, but did you try the "inspect element" of your browsers Dev Tool? It should be something like "H1" oder "H2" either with a font-size in px or em. To remove the a-tag you'll need some Javascript, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id (to keep it short: This is all you need `document.getElementById("element-id").outerHTML = "";`)